# I want to send notification push notification to android phone

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification push notification to android phone ( app build in flutter) from nodejs server.

I have registered in firebase and registered android app, downloaded google-services.json and copied to flutter application.

In firebase service account, I have generated the key and copied to nodejs server.

I have installed firebase messaging package in flutter and firebase admin in nodejs. I am receiving device token from flutter app to nodejs backend I am trying to send the message using below code.

**(I dont have any user in firebase storages).**

Error I am receiving is :
FirebaseMessagingError: tokens must be a non-empty array
at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
errorInfo: {
code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
message: 'tokens must be a non-empty array'
},
codePrefix: 'messaging'
}

```
var serviceAccount = require("../../config/serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
module.exports = {
  sendPushNotification: (registrationToken) => {
    try {
      // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
      var message = {
        data: {
          score: '850',
          time: '2:45'
        },
        token: registrationToken
      };
      admin.messaging().sendMulticast(message)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.results[0].error);
          console.log(response.successCount + ' messages were sent successfully');
      });
      } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you are sending an empty(null) `registrationToken`

You can check that by printing the `registrationToken` using `Console.log(registrationToken)`

So you have to check the method that invokes `sendPushNotification` and make sure that you are sending a valid token.